# Exchange server accepts email without authentication. Is this a misconfiguration?

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, email-server

I am a user on a network with an exchange server and there is an HP scanner/email machine that can send emails with scanned docs as an attachment from any email address without authentication so I thought this was odd, so I looked up a way using PowerShell to send an email using:

> New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("1.1.1.1"), \n $smtp.Send("to@example.com","from@example.com","subj","body")

Is this a misconfiguration? I can send an email from any internal email address (I've only tested our domain email addresses) and these can be sent inside and outside our network.

Comment: So you're saying that the scanner can send email to any email address that the Exchange server is **NOT** authoritative for, such as gmail.com, hotmail.com, etc.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because open-ended discussion questions are a poor fit for Server Fault.

Comment: jeepers these communities sure are friendly, where would be a more appropriate place to ask this kind of question?

Answer (score 0):

Are you the administrator of the Exchange server?  I'm trying to understand the context of your question.

If you're sending emails from a domain-authenticated workstation, you *are* authenticated (with [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication)).  Similarly, if the HP scanner/email machine is logged into the domain, it is also authenticated.

If the HP scanner/email machine is *not* a domain member, and is sending emails to internal email addresses, well, the Exchange server is authoritative for that domain and that should succeed (although they may be filtered as spam).  If it's sending them externally and not a domain member, I assume that you (or the Exchange Admin) have created an exception of some kind for that machine.

Comment: Thanks for the link, from a security perspective why wouldn't the exchange server verify or force the from@example.com to be the same as the credentials from the user logged in?

Comment: It does verify the connection.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772815%28WS.10%29.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  As for the return address, it only requires that you give valid credentials when authenticating (via NTLM/Kerberos).

Comment: Have you ever seen an example where the return address is authenticated against the user? Or is this more of an afterthought as you would be able to tell who was sending bogus mail?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not *necessarily* a misconfiguration.

It is a default setting that is often left in place precisely so that dumb devices like printers and scanners can email documents to users.  It also happens to reduce the effort required by the sysadmin(s) to set up email alerts from all manner of applications and devices that may or may not be technically capable of providing authentication, so it's a fairly common occurrence to see mail servers that accept unauthenticated mail from at least some internal addresses.

As you've noted, there is something of an associated security concern - accepting any unauthenticated from internal networks allows malicious use of unauthenticated email for spam purposes, and I've seem more than a few companies get their mailservers blacklisted because some user got infected with a piece of malware that then used the corporate email server to spew out spam.  Provided that IT has the manpower and resources to devote to addressing it, this concern is generally mitigated or dealt with by configuring the relevant Exchange receive connector to only accept unauthenticated emails from the specific IPs of devices that need to send unauthenticated email, or from specific VLANs where these devices reside.